# ValueError: multiclass-multioutput format is not supported using sklearn roc_auc_score function

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am using `logistic regression` for prediction. My predictions are `0's` and `1's`. After training my model on given data and also when training on important features i.e `X_important_train` see screenshot. I am getting score around 70% but when I use `roc_auc_score(X,y)` or `roc_auc_score(X_important_train, y_train)` I am getting value error:
 `ValueError: multiclass-multioutput format is not supported`

Code:

```
# Load libraries
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score

# Standarize features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_std = scaler.fit_transform(X)

# Train the model using the training sets and check score
model.fit(X, y)
model.score(X, y)

model.fit(X_important_train, y_train)
model.score(X_important_train, y_train)

roc_auc_score(X_important_train, y_train)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: what are the shapes of `X_important_train, y_train`?

Comment: @seralouk  X_important_train (51202, 7) and  y_train (51202,)

Comment: you should get the predictions of the model and then use them in the `roc_auc_score`. what you are doing is not correct. You use the TRAINING data as inputs in the `roc_auc_score`  + the shapes should be same

Comment: @seralouk Yes got it. I should use `roc_auc_score(y_test, y_important_pred)` and `roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)`. Can you write an answer.

Comment: just a quick question...how would you define your roc without telling the system how you did? The syntax, as you can read from the error Traceback and the docs, `roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score)` does not correspond to `roc_auc_score(X,y)`

Comment: @Uvar got it thanks.

Comment: @stonerock i hope that now it is clear. bests

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First of all, the `roc_auc_score` function expects input arguments with the same shape.**

```
sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, average=’macro’, sample_weight=None)

Note: this implementation is restricted to the binary classification task or multilabel classification task in label indicator format.

y_true : array, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_classes]
True binary labels in binary label indicators.

y_score : array, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_classes]
Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions (as returned by “decision_function” on some classifiers).
```

**Now, the inputs are the true and predicted scores, NOT the training and label data as you are using in the example that you posted.**
**In more detail,**

```
model.fit(X_important_train, y_train)
model.score(X_important_train, y_train)
# this is wrong here
roc_auc_score(X_important_train, y_train)
```

**You should so something like:**

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_data)
roc_auc_score(y_true, y_pred)
```